# OpenShift Online, NodeJS, Jenkins, and package dependencies - can someone explain?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, openshift

I'm running a NodeJS app on Openshift using Jenkins for building deployments (and I'm pretty new to both Node and cloud-based servers). My app depends on a package that has a binary component, so I can't just check it into git - it fails when it's executed on the server. I'm wondering what's the best way to deploy these sorts of dependencies. I see that there is an $OPENSHIFT_DEPENDENCIES_DIR (as well as $OPENSHIFT_BUILD_DEPENDENCIES_DIR), but I can't find any information about how (or if) these can be utilized for node modules. It would be great if I could keep all my dependencies on the server and out of my source tree.

Thanks!

Update: I forgot to mention that I need to apply a patch to the package in question, which is why I can't just rely on it being auto-installed via package.json. Plus, it seems awfully redundant/slow to rebuild all your dependencies on every deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to nodejs. I've been playing with nodeJs for about 6 months from now. As for my personal experience [nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/) is the best cloud-hosting service for nodejs. As I said so due to the following reasons.

1. You can simply install jitsu command line in your terminal
2. Your app can be deployed with all the dependencies and databases using the package.json file
3. They support all the types of sockets either

A very good alternative for jitsu is [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) But sometimes heroku fails with Socket.IO and stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty invested in OpenShift, which, fwiw, also has a command-line management tool and also supports dependencies via package.json. I forgot to mention that I need to apply a patch to the module in question, so I can't have the package just auto-managed. Plus, if I rebuilt all my packages on every deploy, that would be really slow.